# Rails locales have messed up named routes in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, internationalization

I just decided to add multiple languages to my rails app. I've wrapped my routes with this

```
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :courses
    # more routes
  end
```

And my application_controller

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
end

def default_url_options(options = {})
  {locale: I18n.locale}
end
```

In my feature test I had this in my test

```
    visit course_path(free_course)
```

I'm getting the following error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"courses", :id=>nil, 
:locale=>#<Course id: 4068, name: "Mabelle Kirlin III", description: "Ut voluptas eum praesentium dolore repudiandae. Eo...", main_image_url: nil, premium_course: false, slug: "mabelle-kirlin-iii", created_at: "2017-12-03 16:44:53", updated_at: "2017-12-03 16:44:53", published: true, preview_text: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The course.id (the model) is getting passed in as the locale. I thought the `(:locale)` meant that the locale was an optional param. In my testing is there a way to set the locale in block so I don't have to pass params to each named route?

Comment: Can you do `visit course_path(id: free_course.id)`?

Comment: Yep. That fixed it! I won't have to change this in my views, will I?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be required.